# number of blocks, and size of padding at 64bit

Tags: block-cipher, des, padding, blocksize

> A message has 2003 characters, encrypted using a block cipher of 64 bits. What is the size of the padding and the number of blocks?

I tried this, but I'm sure it's not the right thing:

- 2003 mod 64 = 19, this is the number of bits that needs padding.
- 2003 / 64 = 31, this is the number of complete blocks, this + 1 = 32 is the total number of blocks.

Comment: @poncho Presumably a character is supposed to have 8 bits. So you need to either compute `2003 * 8 % 64` (in bits) or `2003 % 8` (in bytes).

Comment: @CodesInChaos: sorry about that; somehow, I read that as '2003 bits'...

Answer (score 2):

As written, this exercise is ambiguous, since we don't know how many bits make one character, or even if this number is constant or not.  (For e.g. Unicode text using the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding, it's not — one character can take up between 1 to 4 bytes, or 8 to 32 bits.)

However, *if* we assume that one character = one byte = 8 bits, then the message has 2003 × 8 = 16024 bits.  This amounts to 250 (= 16000 / 64) full 64-bit cipher blocks, and 24 bits (= 3 bytes) left over, for a total of 251 blocks (= 251 × 64 = 16064 bits) after padding.

(A perhaps simpler way to calculate this is to note that 64 bits = 8 bytes, and that 2000 is a multiple of 8.  Thus, the message has 2000 / 8 = 250 full blocks and 3 extra bytes, giving a total of 2008 bytes after 5 padding bytes have been appended to round the length up to the next multiple of 8 bytes.)

Comment: Assuming ECB mode of operation,  or CBC mode of operation *without* ciphertext stealing.

Comment: ...or, more generally, any mode of operation that requires padding the message to a whole number of cipher blocks.